# Typescript types that can be overwritten based on type arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to tell the typescript compiler that a function that returns `T | null` will definitely be `T` in certain circumstances.

Perhaps I'm thinking about this wrong in which case I'm also open to new ideas, here is the snippet:

```
type ValueOrNull<T, N> = N extends false ? T | null : T;

export function getCookie<T = any, N = false>(name: string): ValueOrNull<T, N> {
  const match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));

  if (match) {
    const [, , value] = match;

    return parseCookieValue(value) as T;
  }

  return null;
}
```

My thinking was if I could call the function as follows: `getCookie<TMyCookie, true>("my_cookie")` that typescript would know that I'm sure the cookie would be there, and the function would not return null. For example after a successful login.

`N extends false ?` feels wrong but `N === false` doesn't work.

the compiler error is `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ValueOrNull<T, N>'.ts(2322)`

Thanks a lot

Comment: That's from within your function, meaning your attempt worked, but you are trying to return something which is potentially `null`. Note i don't say what you are doing is imho design-wise good or bad, just commenting on the error.

Comment: Use this `return null as ValueOrNull<T, N>;`

Comment: everytime one uses `as` one dilutes the utility of typing at all.

Comment: do you have an alternative @pilchard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that fairly easily with function overloads and a second parameter; that also lets you build in a useful explanatory error when (inevitably) the programmer "knows" the cookie exists but it dooesn't:

```typescript
export function getCookie<T>(name: string, required: true): T;
export function getCookie<T>(name: string, required?: false): T | null;
export function getCookie<T>(name: string, required?: boolean): T | null {
    const match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));

    if (match) {
        const [, , value] = match;
        // You'll want to put your `parseCookingvalue` back here,
        // the `as any as T` is just because we don't have that
        // function available to use in the question.
        return /*parseCookieValue(value)*/ value as any as T;
    } else if (required) {
        throw new Error(`Required cookie "${name}" was not found`);
    }
    return null;
}

const a = getCookie<string>("a", true);
//    ^? −−−− type is string
const b = getCookie<string>("b", false);
//    ^? −−−− type is string | null
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwObAwDCEEA1psADwAqAfABQoCGAtsAFxwDOMUmKPABo4UYAEckmMQBMufJMACUXGgG4AUKEixEqDNlwFipCtXpM2nHnwHDREqbID8XBMwA23ZargAfOBQkDw9NbWh4ZHQsHHxCEnJKWkYWdi5efkERMUlpYBlXOAAjUg9gZhQVOBp-QOCPOABvDThWuDQcXjhWZhg0AAs4AF44GQg0JHYUGAA6DsTgGZ6+-qZgAHc4ACVgPABRcAYAcgYAPQClI7gAakCrG7gjoYYAbVO1AF1ry6UlTRa2pgEHAGMsBkomgC2m0Oigui8RCIAG6eRQfYbdXoDTTQ6EAejxcAAmhAkEcQnB1hV4DAIHAwEh4ABPUlQOAAAzAzCg3gSFEEKI8inZxWYaDIcH6wDEQihuIJcBgUo5zG4cAqTPVapoIswaoAVkgukVgGhmEbgJTLWMUEd4P1mEjLUrenL8YSogZYo7mJgPMwimVFXSLXABIrlZJgLxDDM3W0xDAkFBcHiAFRcnnAPmUABqqOADEFiiUacJxctqvVKE1VfUcoAvnBgF5LUCQTknPkIc1cW0lVAIJsUBs4HsoIOoAx2TtcrJ2qZKHAAEQAEkaqWADeXlKrKAgkVJKBk7L+jblieTuCCIU0DY0GlhXWYGOMOeoGTsjGXzGXIgUyiaAqbSnM4j6dPARSvvEi4frYgjfkUf6IJ43hnsBrSgRoQA)

---

Here's an alternative for you, though: You could leave `getCookie` fairly simple and have a general-use [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that you can use anywhere you get back something that may be `null` or `undefined` and you "know" it's not `null` or `undefined`:

```typescript
export function getCookie<T>(name: string): T | null {
    const match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));

    if (match) {
        const [, , value] = match;
        // You'll want to put your `parseCookingvalue` back here,
        // the `as any as T` is just because we don't have that
        // function available to use in the question.
        return /*parseCookieValue(value)*/ value as any as T;
    }
    return null;
}

export function assertIsNotNullish<T>(value: T | null | undefined): asserts value is T {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new Error(`Expected non-nullish value, got ${value}`);
    }
}

const a = getCookie<string>("a");
assertIsNotNullish(a);
console.log(a);
//          ^? −−−− type is string
const b = getCookie<string>("b");
console.log(b);
//          ^? −−−− type is string | null
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-iglagDAOgTAiJgiakOAAtEWg3BNW08L64AASBSao0HQrfE02xpaZgDAjEGWUKi8fiCRgAImYO5ngLdME9Pr9AaDDGYM4XEAZthkEDwV5nvzLajCAH4lAv4Pdl4QFyyhufACHgu73AeRS3vej7Pvcr6TO+qhfkoQA)

Comment: This is pretty neat, the `assertIsNotNullish` function is pretty much what I was looking for in terms of telling the compiler a value would be truthy. Didn't know about the ts asserts feature at all tbh so thanks for that!

Comment: @pacifica94 - They're underdocumented, not in the main handbook at all, but described in the [TypeScript 3.7 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). Happy coding!